# Import XML with local HTML

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I created this HTML file to add TPLs and a Search Engine to IE11:

```
<div>
<a href="javascript:window.external.msAddTrackingProtectionList('https://easylist-msie.adblockplus.org/adwarefilters.tpl','Adware filter')">Adware filter</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:window.external.msAddTrackingProtectionList('https://easylist-msie.adblockplus.org/easylist.tpl','EasyList')">EasyList</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:window.external.msAddTrackingProtectionList('https://easylist-msie.adblockplus.org/easyprivacy.tpl','EasyPrivacy')">EasyPrivacy</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:window.external.msAddTrackingProtectionList('https://easylist-msie.adblockplus.org/fanboy-annoyance.tpl','Fanboy Annoyances')">Fanboy Annoyances</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:window.external.msAddTrackingProtectionList('https://easylist-msie.adblockplus.org/malwaredomains_full.tpl','Malware Domains')">Malware Domains</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:window.external.AddSearchProvider('./Google.xml')">add Google</a>
</div>
```

Adding TPLs fork flawless, but somehow I can't add the custom search engine.
When I change it to this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.external.AddSearchProvider('https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/IEGallery/GoogleAddOns')">add Google</a>
```

it works, but it doesn't when its a local file. I even downloaded the xml manually from Microsoft, still it didn't work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue :

1. Location of your xml file.
2. XML specified on
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/IEGallery/GoogleAddOns is invalid.(When you store it on local machine.)

Fix :

1. Put your xml on correct location
2. To validate that xml you have to escape ampersands ('&') in given xml. To do so replace all '&' with '&' in your xml and your code will work.I tested this on my machine.

Hope this will work for you.

You can check following screenshot. After changes Your code is working for me .

[image]

My Folder structure :

books.xml contains GoogleAddOns xml content.
And my html code for xml file

```
<a href="javascript:window.external.AddSearchProvider('./books.xml')">add
        Google</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 2. actually does work, as it's the same link on Microsoft's search plugin gallery. Both the HTML file and XML file are in the same directory, yet they don't work. Am I typing the path wrong?

Comment: Have replaced your & with &amp; in local xml file?

Comment: yes, I uploaded my XML to pastebin and linked the raw paste to my HTML and it worked. But I can't get it work when it' accessed locally

Comment: Share tour xml with me or Validate it online on http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator

Comment: What error you are getting when you are clicking on that link?

Comment: IE says: The search provider couldn't be added. 1. the file cannot be downloaded 2. the website is offline 3. there is no internet connection. So more or less it's an access error. Funnily enough, its easier to access the internet than a damned local file

Comment: I added my forder structure for your refernce. Issue is with you location if you are getting above error

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. And I'm at a loss here. Nothing changes, xml in root, xml in a subdirectory, nope. The same error. Double checked the path's and yet it doesn't

Comment: Are you able to open xml using browser? Try http://localhost:8080/<WebAppName>/<XMLPath>

Comment: I can open the xml without any problems, but I'm not hosting the HTML. It will be used completely locally, double click and add Filters and Search Engines etc.

Comment: Actually I gave up, I just pasted the xml on pastebin and linked it into the document. I just need to refresh the HTML if the paste should get removed.